# how to see my private key bye decrypted wallet.dat

Tags: private-key, altcoin, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

How to decrypted my wallet.dat (Yes, I know the password) so i can see my private key? if anyone can help there is 1 LTC for them

Comment: If this was Bitcoin core you would enter the password and use dumpwallet from the console or cli

Comment: why is my comment deleted/ disabled?

Comment: You're posting comments as answers. They're being converted to actual comments (which you don't have permission to create yourself, presumably).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: you may have misunderstood me i want to decrypted wallet.dat file not using the console

Comment: Hello Al Mos, it seemed that you were replying to Luca Blight, but you created an answer post instead of commenting on Luca's answer. If you were trying to respond to RedGrittyBrick's comment on your question, you should have added a comment there. --Answers on Stackexchange compete with each other they don't have a fixed order, so using them to respond to previous posts will not work.

Comment: Please check out our [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bitcoin Core:

1 - Go to window > console

2 - Type `listunspent`

3 - You will get a list of addresses with the spendable amount

4 - Copy one of those addresses

5 - Type `dumpprivkey pasteYourAddressHere`

Comment: you may have misunderstood me i want to decrypted wallet.dat file not using the console

Comment: First you need to know which software this wallet.dat comes from, many softwares use different types of wallet.dat.